# How to make a view's size depend on another view's size?

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm making a UI designed as shown below. View 1 is an image, when showing different pictures, its size will be different. The sizes of view 2 and view 3 are depend on View 1. How to define the xml file to make this happen?

ps: The design came from client so I can't change it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

better use RelativeLayout to achieve this task....Make appropriate changes and use it

```
 <RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <TextView
          android:layout_below="@id/view1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <TextView
         android:layout_toRightof="@id/view1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think LinearLayout is better here, because the easiest way to set the appropriate sizes is to use layout_weight. If you set a non-zero weight for only one element in a LinearLayout, then it will take all the remaining space. layout_weight divides the remaining spaces in the ratio of the given weights. It calculates the size of the remaining space after setting the given layout_width-s (or height) first, then it will override these sizes. When you want to divide the whole screen into fixed ratios, not the remaining spaces after some initial setting, then you should first set the size of the elements to 0. So set the size of View1 to wrap_content, and all the other sizes in the appropriate directions to 0 (fill parent in the other direction), and use layout_weight=1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width ="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src=.../>
    <SomeKindOfView
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1"/> 
  </LinearLayout>
  <AnotherView
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    android:layout_width="0px"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```